# How to stop Laravel valet auto-start in Mac OS

Tags: macos, laravel-5

the valet server conflict with apache , How to stop the auto-start ,
What is the principle of the auto start ?
thanks!

Comment: you may find a solution with `/valet/cli/stubs/daemon.plist`

Answer (score 8):

If you run `valet uninstall` you will have to reinstall valet if you want to use it. What I've done on my install was to removing launch agents from registered on-start-up services. In order to do so you have to use launchctl :

```
launchctl remove homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq
launchctl remove homebrew.mxcl.nginx
launchctl remove homebrew.mxcl.php
launchctl remove homebrew.mxcl.php@7.4; //and other versions of php loaded.
```

See https://rakhesh.com/mac/macos-launchctl-commands/

Then you if you want to start valet you will have to do

```
valet start
```

See [https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/valet#other-valet-commands/](https://rakhesh.com/mac/macos-launchctl-commands/)

If you want to stop all the services then type in the command line

```
valet stop
```

Answer (score 4):

To temporarily stop Valet when not in use run `valet stop`

This stops Valet services and prevents the above conflict issues. You can also run `valet start` to start Valet services again.

To see all Valet services run `valet list`

Answer (score 3):

Running `valet uninstall` will also remove a lot of things you might wish to keep. So I ran `composer global remove laravel/valet` in order to remove valet but keep nginx etc as is.

Answer (score 2):

Run in terminal: `valet uninstall`
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/valet#other-valet-commands